# Omniauth with Devise - Handling invitation scenarios

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth

I'm integrating Omniauth and Devise into my first ever ruby on rails application.  Currently working the google.

It works, and I love it all.  I can successfully register by clicking a link in my app, authenticating in google, then redirecting back... all as expected.

I need to support a current user inviting new users to work on projects together.  To do this, I allow the current user to create the new user row, specifying the email address of the new user.  The row is added as a stub, so work can be assigned to the new user.

I expect that the new user would register at some point after this by clicking the google link in my app, authenticating in google, then redirecting back into my app.

When this happens, i get this error:

```
1 error prohibited this user from being saved:
Email has already been taken
```

I understand why, but I'm struggling trying to find the correct hooks I can & should use change the behavior to allow the registering user to take over the stubbed user row created for him.

**Edit:**
list of relevant gems (I think):

```
 - devise (2.2.3)
 - oauth (0.4.7)
 - oauth2 (0.8.1)
 - omniauth (1.1.3)
 - omniauth-facebook (1.4.1, 1.4.0)
 - omniauth-google (1.0.2)
 - omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.1.13)
 - omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
 - omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1, 1.0.3)
```

**Edit - devise modules**

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
```

Comment: What devise modules are you current using?

Comment: is this what you are looking for?  devise (2.2.3)

Comment: No, devise has some modules that you can use or not, such as `registerable` , `confirmable` and many others.

Comment: gotcha, thanks and sorry!  FYI, I basically followed ryanb's railscast.....     from my user.rb devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

Comment: Ok, try to remove the `registerable` module.

Comment: Got this:  undefined local variable or method `new_user_registration_url' for #<OmniauthCallbacksController:0x4743708>   -----  I'll look deeper, but dont want to hold you up!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27668/discussion-between-doug-and-kleber-s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answer....

I never did find a way to modify the behavior, so put a hack in.  I created a new table to hold invitations that is inserted into when a person who is not registered is invited.  The first time the invitee comes to the site, I automatically accept the invitations.

Seems there should be a more elegant solution for this...  feel free to share for posterity!

Comment: Refer to this gist: https://gist.github.com/travisp/2007222?permalink_comment_id=1001602